# Connecting to RDS (postgres) from the lambda function which is written in python

Tags: amazon-web-services

There is a use-case where I need to connect to my RDS instance which postgres from my lambda which is written in python. I need to execute some queries and upload the output to s3 bucket. Can someone please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is make sure your lambda is running inside of your VPC and assign it a security group. Then in the security group you are using for your RDS instance edit it to allow inbound traffic from the security group your lambda is using on port 5432. This should allow your lambda to connect to your RDS instance.

Comment: I'm able to connect now. Thanks